# Linq subselect filter

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, subquery

probably someone can help me with this (at least for me) complicated problem.

Lets say i have the following data (in DB)

```
Tab1 (id_t1): Item
  (1)
  (2)
  (3)

Tab2 (id_t2, id_t1): Group
  (4, 1)
  (5, 1)
  (6, 2)
  (7, 3)

Tab3 (id_t3, id_t2, v): GroupField
  (10, 4, 100) 
  (11, 4, 300)
  (12, 5, 200)
  (13, 6, 100)
  (14, 6, 200)  
  (15, 7, 100)
  (16, 7, 300)
```

Now i'd like to select all Items that include all of some specific GroupFields.

Eg. i have v = list(100,200)

and i like to get back 1,2 but not 3

1 because Group4 holds the Field10 with v=100 and Group5 holds Field12 with v=200

and 2 because Group6 holds Field13 with v=100 and Field14 with v=200

Is something like this possible in Linq? (i allready tried different ways (any/all) but without success so far.

I don't get the point how to overcome that "field can be in any Group and not all in one Group"...

I don't even know how to do this in SQL in one command without using temp-tables/cursors.

_rene

Comment: I don't understand the logic. What would be the result of your sample if field 14 was for group 4 or 7 or 8?

Comment: If field14 was for group 4 (item1) the result would be only 1 because group 6 would not include field 200.

Comment: But:...

i got it working in SQL. Pretty simple .... i'l propbably take some sleep before i go further :)

select distinct id_t1 from Tab1 t1
join Tab2 t2 on t1.id_t1=t2.id_t1
join Tab3 t3 on t2.id_t2=t2.id_t3
group by id_t1, v
having v in(100,200)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result =
    groups.Join(fields, o => o.Id, i => i.GroupId,
                (o, i) => new { Group = o, Field = i } )
          .GroupBy(x => x.Group.ItemId)
          .Where(x => values.All(y => x.Any(z => z.Field.Value == y)))
          .Select(x => x.Key)
          .Distinct();
```

The following classes are used:

```
class Group
{
    public Group(int id, int itemId)
    {
        Id = id;
        ItemId = itemId;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
}

class GroupField
{
    public GroupField(int id, int groupId, int value)
    {
        Id = id;
        GroupId = groupId;
        Value = value;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

and the following initialization:

```
var groups = new [] { new Group(4, 1), new Group(5, 1),
                      new Group(6, 2), new Group(7, 3) };

var fields = new [] { new GroupField(10, 4, 100),
                      new GroupField(11, 4, 300), 
                      new GroupField(12, 5, 200),  
                      new GroupField(13, 6, 100),  
                      new GroupField(14, 6, 200),  
                      new GroupField(15, 7, 100),  
                      new GroupField(16, 7, 300)
                    };

var values = new [] { 100, 200 };
```

Comment: +1 for the three levels nested Where/All/Any lambda! That's what separates the men/women from the boys/girls. :-)

Comment: Hey Daniel thanks for your answer. Just figured out, my SQL was not realy correct after all. Your code does not produce the results it should. It returns 1 and 2 but 1 is not ok, because neither group4 or 5 include value 100. So what i basicly try do do: Get all items that inculde at least those fields that have 100 and 200 as value. But those fields can be in different groups and not even all in one group.

Comment: @renemarxis: My code matches your specification, I quote: "and i like to get back 1,2", furthermore you said: "1 because Group4 holds the Field10 with v=100 and Group5 holds Field12 with v=200". Item 1 needs to be returned, because it has the values 100 and 200, 100 via Group 4 -> Field 10 and 200 via Group 5 -> Field 12. Why you say group 4 doesn't include value 100 I don't know.

Comment: Ahhh mistake from my side. very sorry. i did oversee that you initialise the group 4 with 100. sorry. I'l try againe

Comment: Works like a charm ... now i have to understand exactly what you are doing in there and then transform it to vb ... many thanks